# Problemas con crear slug

Tags: python, django

hola buenas tardes estoy desarrollando una aplicacion la cual maneja dos roles administrador y desarrollador, los datos de administrador como desarrollador se crean sin problemas pero al momento de tratar de usar slug el programa no los reconoce.

este es mi modelo

```
class ProfileAdministrator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Administrator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.png', upload_to='profiles/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug


class ProfileDeveloper(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Developer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.png', upload_to='profiles/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug


@receiver(post_save, sender=Administrator)
def set_profile_administrator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        ProfileAdministrator.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Developer)
def set_profile_developer(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        ProfileDeveloper.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(pre_save, sender=ProfileAdministrator)
def set_slug_profile_administrator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.user:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.user)


@receiver(pre_save, sender=ProfileDeveloper)
def set_slug_profile_administrator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.user:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.user)
```

el programa funciona bien hasta cuando ingreso los slug, no los reconoce, pero los datos se crean de forma correcta

Comment: que seria "no los reconoce"? te tira un error? como estas tratando de usarlos?

Comment: ya me di cuenta del problema y es que estaba llamando a los signals, de la misma manera